# SimpleForm required field (*) are not disappear even config at config.wrappers :default

Tags: simple-form

I try to config simple_form to always set all fields NOT required by default.

But I still need this when I put `:required => true` in the view.

Then I go to `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` and set it like this.

```
  config.wrappers :default, :class => :input, :required => false,
    :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|
```

and set `config.required_by_default = false`

But asterisk still show up.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's also possible to change SimpleForm setup.

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
  config.required_by_default = false
end
```

Take this into account: (taken from [simple form github page](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form))

> Required fields are marked with an * prepended to their labels.
>
> By default all inputs are required. When the form object includes
>   ActiveModel::Validations (which, for example, happens with Active
>   Record models), fields are required only when there is presence
>   validation. Otherwise, Simple Form will mark fields as optional. For
>   performance reasons, this detection is skipped on validations that
>   make use of conditional options, such as :if and :unless.

Answer (score 1):

Rafaiel,

I had the same problem in Rails 4.0, not sure what you're using. 
The best solution I've found is to go to `config/locales/simple_form.en.yml` and change the first lines like this (the `mark:` line is the one you change):

```
en:
  simple_form:
    "yes": 'Yes'
    "no": 'No'
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: ''  #mark was previously '*', which puts an asterisk in the display!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it not solution. Because I still need the required field, just not show it by default. :)

Comment: So you are trying to change your default settings so that required => true is no longer the default?